# Assign Logged in User to Textbox inside a FormView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net, formview

ASP.Net using C#
I am in need of correct syntax. This is critical at this point. I need to assign the Authenticated/Logged in user to a Textbox inside a FormView control (FormView1 to be exact)! I can't get this any further and I am asking for help. I want to admit upfront that I don't have a full grasp of this and if you can help please, please provide the correct code. I know what I have is wrong but I'm just showing what I am trying to do so far. I am doing an insert of the Form's data into a database table in SQL Server. Error message: Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'Submitted_by_email' does not exist in the current context echodevelopment C:\Users\dmartin\source\repos\echodevelopment\echodevelopment\Submitinitialrequest.aspx.cs  30  Active

```
     protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
        {
            TextBox TGG = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("Submitted_by_email");
            TGG.Text = Submitted_by_email.Text;
        }

        if (submitted_by_email != null)
        {
            _ = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                submitted_by_email.Text = User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You first code grabs submitted_by_email, and shoves result into TGG. but you next if tries to use submitted_by_email, which the first few lines shows you have to use findcontrol to referance submitted_by_email. So, any place in that code needs to use findcontrol to use/get/refernce submitted_by_email. Either use find control one time outside of the mode test, or in your 2nd if  you have to do a findcontrol again. So any code that tries to use submitted_by_email will not work - you have to use findcontrol into a referance first. Now if the first findcontrol fails, then the control name is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox MyTextBox = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("TextBoxID");

       MyTextBox.Text = User.Identity.Name;
    }

}
```

}